# Offer the possibility to preview a personalized product

Tags: javascript, image-processing, image-manipulation

I want to give my clients the possibility to preview their personalized product.
In a nutshell, personalization means the user specifies some text and positions the text somewhere on an image of the product.

A great example of what I'd like to achieve is [this](http://www.thingsremembered.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TRproduct_10001_9951_639280_?int=639280_img&position=HP3#resultsTop). Select a frame size and then hit Personalize, after you select the occasion and add the text you can chose to preview the product.

The hardest thing to do here, as I see it, is to generate the image. The positioning of text will probably be made in javascript.

Do you have any recommendations?

Just as a note, using scene7 is not a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page does not work for FireFox Mac OS-X:

```
Error: s_dc is not defined
File: http://imagestr.thingsremembered.com/wcsstore/CustomB2CStorefrontAssetStoreTR/javascript/lightbox.js
Line: 427
```

If you really want to do this only by JavaScript you could use Canvas or SVG.

But I guess it would be way easier using PHP Perl or Flash.

This would also increase your cross browser compability.

Comment: That's a very good point... If you don't need client side interaction, then do it all on the server...